# error "java.lang.StackOverflowError:" when try to save object in Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am new to the firebase.
I tried to save the properties of the users listed in my application into the database `Firebase`, this is code

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            firebaseuser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (firebaseuser != null) {
                finish();
                firebaseuser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                String nama = firebaseuser.getDisplayName();
                String mail = firebaseuser.getEmail();
                //String pass = password.getText().toString();
                String id = firebaseuser.getUid();
                //Uri gambar = firebaseuser.getPhotoUrl();
                member1 = new Member(nama, mail, "", "belum", "belum", "belum", id);
                datab.getReference("member").push().setValue(member1);
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HalamanUtama.class));
            }
        }
    };
```

the problem here is when I get into my application using the Google sign in, I can not save the information of the user who signed in to my application with google to my firebase database, but I can save the user's login information using email method.
This is the code to get into my application using email

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString())
                        .addOnCompleteListener(HalamanPendaftaran.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    progressdialog.dismiss();
                                    finish();
                                    firebaseuser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                    String nama = firebaseuser.getDisplayName();
                                    String mail = firebaseuser.getEmail();
                                    String pass = password.getText().toString();
                                    String id = firebaseuser.getUid();
                                    Uri gambar = firebaseuser.getPhotoUrl();
                                    member1 = new Member(nama, mail, pass, "belum", "belum", "belum", id, gambar);
                                    datab.getReference("member").push().setValue(member1);
                                    startActivity(new Intent(HalamanPendaftaran.this, HalamanUtama.class));
                                } else {
                                    progressdialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(HalamanPendaftaran.this, "tidak dapat mendaftarkan user, tolong coba lagi !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    email.setText("");
                                    password.setText("");
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

As for the error I get when trying to store user data that sign in using google

```
01-10 18:42:00.619 8218-8218/com.example.asus.fastapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.asus.fastapp, PID: 8218
java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza.zzaF(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzax(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzaE
```

This is one of the data of the user who successfully saved
[Firebase Database data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK8PD.jpg)

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I wasn't able to find any errors, but I was wondering why you are calling `finish()` that early on?

Comment: em, it is used to move between activity. the problem is in the code " datab.getReference("member").push().setValue(member1);"

Comment: I know what it is for, but I was just wondering why you call it that early in the code instead of later. I think you should not be calling `finish()` that early on. Try calling it after actually starting the new activity.

Comment: oh ok I'll change it, but the problem is not solved yet

Comment: You are also getting the current user twice. Once before you check if the `user != null` and once after. Could you provide your `Member.class`? I guess something is wrong with that.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/kVjR4b7W here it is

Comment: Try commenting this line `firebaseuser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();` and let `firebaseuser` object be the previous one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your `Member` class contains a field of type `Uri`.  `Uri` is not [one of the native types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#setValue(java.lang.Object)) that Firebase serializes.

Change your `Member` class to store the Uri as a String and use [Uri.toString()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#toString()) and [Uri.parse()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse(java.lang.String)) to convert.

Comment: thank you very much, I've been pulling my hairs over night because of this. Firebase should produce more understandable error message instead of spamming this line `com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi$zza`