# How to write an object with an ArrayList<> attribute to Firebase database (Android)?

Tags: android, list, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to write a Spot object to my Firebase database. All was good an well until I added an ArrayList<> attribute to the Spot class. Now I can no longer write Spot object to the database and when I try, my app just.. stops. No crash, so I don't get any error feedback in the log :/

Here is my writing code:

```
public void writeSpot(Spot spot, AddSpotContract.RequiredModelOps subscriber) {
    Log.i("DBGR", "writing spot");
    getReference().child(spot.getId()).setValue(spot);
    Log.i("DBGR", "what is going on??");//if Spot object has an ArrayList<Uri> attribute, this is never reached
    subscriber.onSpotWritten();
}
```

So does anybody know why I can't write an object with an ArrayList<> attribute to the database? I've tried with an array, but that isn't supported (at least in that case I get the feedback to tell me that).

Thanks a lot :)

EDIT: I found the answer.

It actually had nothing to do with the ArrayList, the issue came from trying to write a Uri to the database, as it isn't a supported class (see [error "java.lang.StackOverflowError:" when try to save object in Firebase Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41567576/error-java-lang-stackoverflowerror-when-try-to-save-object-in-firebase-databa))

Answer (score 1):

In order to write data objects to your `Firebase database`, in stead of using a `List`, use a `Map`. If you have also in your pojo an `Map` field, change it to a `Map`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Alex, your solution didn't work but it caused an error that I could actually use :)

Comment: Yep, im not sure what the etiquette is to answer your own question, so I just made an edit. Thanks for the assist