# App crashing giving 'java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB' error while saving data on firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, runtime-error, stack-overflow, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload/save 3 images & 4 text fields all at once on firebase.

Here's my code:

```
if (!pDescription.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            if (!pDuration.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                if (!pPrice.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    if (imageArray != null) {
                        if (imageArray.size() > 0) {
                            for (int i=0; i<imageArray.size(); i++) {

                                Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(imageArray.get(i).toString()));

                                Log.d("CALLED", "YES1");

                                String key = database.getReference().push().getKey();

                                UploadTask uploadTask = storage.getReference().child(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId()).child(key).child("p_image").putFile(file);
                                uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                                    }
                                }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                        // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                                        @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
                                        Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                                        imageUrls.add(downloadUrl.toString());
                                        String id = database.getReference().push().getKey();
                                        database.getReference().child(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId()).child(id).child("pDescription").setValue(pDescription.getText().toString());
                                        database.getReference().child(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId()).child(id).child("pDuration").setValue(pDuration.getText().toString());
                                        database.getReference().child(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId()).child(id).child("pPrice").setValue(pPrice.getText().toString());
                                        if (imageUrls != null) {
                                            for (int i=0; i<imageUrls.size(); i++) {
                                                Log.d("imageUrlsSize", String.valueOf(imageUrls.size()));
                                                // everything is working fine above this line
                                                // this text is not getting saved on firebase
                                                String idtwo = database.getReference().push().getKey();
                                                database.getReference().child(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId()).child(id).child(idtwo).child("imageUrl").setValue(downloadUrl);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Posted successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        } else {
                            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                    .make(coordinatorLayout, "Upload p's image", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            snackbar.show();
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                            .make(coordinatorLayout, "aaa", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    snackbar.show();
                }
            } else {
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                        .make(coordinatorLayout, "bbb", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                snackbar.show();
            }
        } else {
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(coordinatorLayout, "ccc", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snackbar.show();
        }
```

The images and 3 text fields are getting saved successfully but I think when the the code in line specified in above is reached, app crashes giving this error: `java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB`.

Why is this happening?

Please help me out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41567576/error-java-lang-stackoverflowerror-when-try-to-save-object-in-firebase-databa

Comment: @NovoLucas This worked. You can post an answer here if you want. I will accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are trying to upload data to Firebase which is bigger than the maximum size that is supported. To solve this, you need to upload data in small packages, so the Firebase will accept that data.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your Member class contains a field of type Uri.

> Uri is not one of the native types that Firebase serializes.

Change your Member class to store the Uri as a String and use Uri.toString() and Uri.parse() to convert.

Link to the original post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41567576/7337723).